# INSTAGRAM_STORIES is not working in react-native-share for android 13

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-share

I used react-native-share version 8.0.1 and try to use instagran_stories it's work fine  in android 10 but not in android 13

const result = await Share.shareSingle({
backgroundImage: contentUri,
backgroundBottomColor: '#fefefe',
backgroundTopColor: '#906df4',
social: Share.Social.INSTAGRAM_STORIES,
appId: '89913274497****',
});

I try with all android version but it's not working in android 13 when I share my image to instgram it store my image to gallery and open the image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.